# Is there a better way to fetch text from HTML table using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-python

I've been trying to fetch the text circled in the attached image below.

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoplB.png)

[Website URL](https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/climeon/company_financials)

My Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/ng-component/entity-v2/page-layout/div/div/div/page-centered-layout[3]/div/div/div[1]/row-card[1]/profile-section/section-card/mat-card/div[2]/div/list-card/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div')
```

And below is the output of my code:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/ng-component/entity-v2/page-layout/div/div/div/page-centered-layout[3]/div/div/div[1]/row-card[1]/profile-section/section-card/mat-card/div[2]/div/list-card/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div"}
```

(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82).

Please how can I resolve this?

Comment: You can loop through the table and get the text using .text. You will have to clarify your question if you want more help than this.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the text "Post-IPO Debt - Climeon" I want to extract, I will need help with the code if you can. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from dynamic table use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and following `xpath`.

```
driver.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/climeon/company_financials")
columnRecords=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[.='Funding Rounds']/following ::table[1]//tbody//tr//td")))

for col in columnRecords:
    print(col.text)
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get the text of each element inside a table.

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/ng-component/entity-v2/page-layout/div/div/div/page-centered-layout[3]/div/div/div[1]/row-card[1]/profile-section/section-card/mat-card/div[2]/div/list-card/div/table/tbody/tr/td')
for x in range(1, len(table) + 1):
    # Here you have to find what number varies between items and 
    # use x instead of that number
    text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'/html/body/chrome/div/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/ng-component/entity-v2/page-layout/div/div/div/page-centered-layout[3]/div/div/div[1]/row-card[1]/profile-section/section-card/mat-card/div[2]/div/list-card/div/table/tbody/tr/td[{x}]/field-formatter/identifier-formatter/a/div/div').text 
    print(text)
```

I used the xpaths in your question but I don't know if they are right so test it out and let me know

Comment: So @DeasSec I tried out the and this is the error message I got: for r in range(1, row + 1):
  File "<ipython-input-61-1413afac21a5>", line 1
    for r in range(1, row + 1):
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: You need to get the length of the table in your case row i guess